# resolv.conf - No DNS servers known

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I am using focal Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (hosted virtual machine)

Occasionally after a reboot DNS resolution fails (e.g. `ping google.com > Resource temporarily unavailable`)

To 'fix' this I reboot the machine.

What is the proper fix and why is this occurring sporadically ?

The contents of `resolv.conf` indicates the file is being managed by `systemd-resolved`

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
# all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
# No DNS Servers known
```

### example error:

```
wal@www:~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: @Nmath question updated. also `How do you know that this is a problem with DNS resolution?` - ping google.com fails (as above) but ping 8.8.8.8 works

Comment: Check the /etc/resolv.conf link, it should point to the stub-resolv.conf, but yours points to the resolv.conf, and for some reason, that file does not contain any DNS servers (Some recommend using that to cut out systemd-resolv completely, but then a real DNS server, like the router should be included).

Comment: you can read through that documentation to configure your symlink for DNS resolving: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved

Comment: What does `sudo systemd-resolve --status` say when this happens?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `/etc/netplan` is empty then netplan does not configure your network.

Your network is probably configured in old ifup/ifdown style.
That means you find the network configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In addition there is systemd-resolve with its DNS configuration file `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` where you can put your DNS configuration in.

```
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888
#FallbackDNS=
Domains=example.com
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

You can check your DNS settings with

```
systemd-resolve --status
```

You can restart systemd-resolve with

```
systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Alternatively you can put your settings in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail` which will be added to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` during boot.

Comment: this answer has helped (i cannot upvote due to reputation being used for bounty) - i'm able to work around the problem by assigning the `DNS` field in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` - when i do this i no longer see the entry with `search` (all entries are `nameserver: ...` - still unsure why prior resolved.conf was seemingly randomly empty

Comment: You probably did not install netplan. I have no idea why. Without netplan you need another way to configure resolv.conf. This is in your case systemd-resolved now. search is probably empty because you did not set the Domains parameter in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 20.04 uses /etc/netplan to set DNS.
Do you have nameservers section in your /etc/netplan/?.yaml file?

yaml-file should have a section similar like this:

```
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
                - 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

resolve.conf is generated from netplan during boot and should should look like this.

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search example.com
```

There is also a /etc/systemd/resolved.conf where static configuration may be strored. You can read more details `man resolved.conf`

Furthermore you can investigate journalctl -b and search for systemd-resolved messages.

Comment: `/etc/netplan` folder is empty (the folder exists however)... `...is generated from netplan during boot and should should look like this` <-- it does look like that now (and is working) but as above on some reboots it is blank -